# iFrame Scroll Event Detecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have searched all over the net and tried many different things, but can't figure out how to detect scrolling of an iframe. The iframe source is on the same server is the same directory as the page. Here is the initial code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var iframe = $('#iframeId');
   iframe.load(function(){
      $(this).scroll(function() {
         alert('scrolling');
      });
   });
   iframe.attr('src','document.html');
});
```

I have tried changing:

```
$(this).scroll(function() {
```

To all this options:

```
$($(this).contents()).scroll(function() {
$($(this).contents().get(0)).scroll(function() {
$($(this).contents().find('html')).scroll(function() {
$($(this).contents().find('body')).scroll(function() {
$($(this).get(0).contentWindow).scroll(function() {
```

I have also tried to add to the iframe html tag:

```
onscroll="alert('scrolling')"
```

Nothing seems to be triggering. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

plain javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var frm = document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow;
      frm.onscroll = function(){
        alert("scrolling...");
      }
    }
</script>
```